# Can I avoid dynamic_cast when subclasses define new member variables?

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm trying to write an application in a "modern" C++ style, while at the same time trying to learn how to do so, and have gotten stuck on a design issue that should be fairly basic.

The application indexes various things, such as files/folders, music (via some music player API, not the filesystem) and perhaps in the future bookmarks and so on.
The issue comes in representing these things. My plan was to use a base class, e.g. `IndexedObject`, which I then subclass into something like `IndexedFile`, `IndexedSong` and so on.

These kinds of objects need to have some members in common, and some not. All kinds need an icon and a name to display in the application, so those clearly go in `IndexedObject`. However, an indexed file needs a full path, whereas an indexed song needs artist, album and title, but we might not know its path (it might not even be located on disk). Storing all of this in a single class seems very ugly, and in that case, I would still need a "type" member to figure out what a particular class instance is supposed to represent.

For the parts of the program where I have an `IndexedObject` but need to access the information only a particular subclass such as `IndexedFile` knows about, is there a better option than using `dynamic_cast`, or is this exactly when it should be used?
By "better", I mean for any reasonable definition of better, such as having higher performance, being safer, and so on. Other options may well include an altogether different design, by the way. This base class/subclass design was just the first thing I thought of.

Update:

A few commenters asked to provide code. However, I don't really have much code that is relevant to this particular question; the question is how I should design and code this (whether the subclass approach is even the right one). I could be super-specific in what I need, but then the answers would become near-useless for anyone other than myself.
I could provide a bit of extra detail about what the goal is, though, so read on if you want that.

The program indexes the various things mentioned in the background, and stores them in an some container type (QVector in my case) for easy retrieval. The user brings the app up via some hotkey, and types in search terms. For each typed letter, the app filters the index, and displays the matches.

For each match found, the UI needs to know its type. If it's a song, perhaps we want to format that as "*artist* - *track name* (from *album*)" or something; if it's a bookmark, perhaps show the domain name and part of the URL, and so on.

So in other words, **if** I use the subclass method, I might do something like:

```
// The real code would of course have a bit more meat with some basic methods

class IndexedObject {
    string name;
    image icon;
};

class IndexedSong : public IndexedObject {
    string artist;
    string title;
};

class IndexedBookmark : public IndexedObject {
    some_url_type url;
};

void displayObject(const IndexedObject &obj) {

    // Pseudo-C++ follows
    if (obj is IndexedSong) {
        display icon, artist and title
    }
    else if (obj is IndexedBookmark) {
        display icon, name and URL;
    }
}
```

... the issue with this example is that the question isn't how to use dynamic_cast, which the example above seems to imply I must, but whether there is an *entirely different way* to solve this problem that avoids dynamic_cast altogether.

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: @Matt I updated with some more information, though I don't have any finished code,  as the question is about *how* to best design this, not about a problem with one particular solution.

Comment: Why do you need inheritance? What's the point of comparing a file to a song?

Comment: The question *is* whether I should use inheritance or not, and if so, how to structure it: "Other options may well include an altogether different design, by the way. This base class/subclass design was just the first thing I thought of." 
However, if I don't, how do I index/cache everything, objects of different types, in a single array? I could theoretically store one array per kind of object, but then I'd need to perform one search per type, combine the results in some way, sort them together, and then display them; that's probably both more difficult and a bit messier IMO.

Comment: See also [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/libs/variant/) for a solution to avoiding polymorphism altogether (I'm a bit disappointed none of the existing answers mentioned this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your code, you could define a virtual function in the base class, and let the sub classes implement that function, which can avoid dynamic_cast. The code will be like this:

```
class IndexedObject {
    string name;
    image icon;
public:
    virtual void display() = 0;
};

class IndexedSong : public IndexedObject {
    string artist;
    string title;
    public:
       virtual void display()
       {/////}
};

class IndexedBookmark : public IndexedObject {
    some_url_type url;
   public:
       virtual void display()
       {/////}
};

void displayObject(const IndexedObject &obj) {

    obj.display()
}
```

The [Open-Closed principle](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/ocp.pdf) is to deal with this case, you can find more details in the url and it talks about how to not use dynamic_cast.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using dynamic_cast, the preferred way is to put the parts that must be done differently for different classes into virtual functions. The term to look for, and learn about, is "polymorphism".

P.S. Maybe it's not a good idea to use inheritance at all - there may be songs which also are files. Composition might work better.

Comment: These classes don't "do" much, though, they are mostly used to store data, so virtual functions are probably not applicable. In some cases, all I need is the icon and name, in which case I can just use a base class pointer/reference. In other cases, I need the specific information stored, such as a file path if it's a file, the album name if it's a song, the URL if it's a bookmark, and so on. It's possible that the information is not always a string, too.

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphic data storage types are a bit of a problem for C++, since good OOP style dictates that the polymorphic behavior should be housed in the subclasses themselves... that is, say, `IndexedObject` would have a pure-virtual `play()` function, and `IndexedSong`'s implementation would play a song, `IndexedVideo`'s would play a video, and so on. But if it's something else consuming the data, it's difficult to make a nice, abstract interface for that.

`dynamic_cast`, enumerations specifying the type, etc. are almost always employed in this situation.

Comment: How are polymorphic types more of a problem in C++ than in, say, Java?

Comment: I disagree with this premise.  Whatever is "consuming" the data stored by an instance of a subclass in this hierarchy should be calling a virtual function to do whatever it needs to "consume" it.  If it needs to be serialized (saved to disk), then each subclass should implement its own version of a virtual function such as serialize() or save() to write XML or JSON or whatever representation is desired.

Comment: @DDrmmr They aren't. Or C# or Smalltalk, for that matter. That whole language family is roughtly the same in this respect.

Comment: @Sneftel Then why do you say it's a problem for C++, specifically?

Comment: @DDrmmr Erm, because C++ is the language the OP is using, as opposed to an OO language which doesn't suffer from this problem.

Comment: @Sneftel That's the opposite of what you just said. Either way, please clarify your answer.

Comment: @DDrmmr I honestly don't understand what you think the contradiction is. C++, Smalltalk, and other languages in that family have problems with runtime polymorphism in data storage types. CLisp, Dylan, and other languages in *that* family do not. As a result, one tends to do more explicit downcasting in C++ than in Dylan.